# addEventListener onerror and error event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image

I have a asp.net control which is loading dyanmically with repeated controls.
I just want a alternative image if image src is not loaded or an error event is fired on an image element,but it is not working

```
<asp:Image ID ="test1" ImageUrl="test1.jpg"  runat="server" CssClass="NotFoundMain" />
<asp:Image ID ="test2" ImageUrl="test14.jpg"  runat="server" CssClass="NotFoundMain" />

 $(document).ready(function () {

        function callImageError(test) {
            console.log(test)
            alert()
        test.setAttribute('src', './Image/WebSiteImage/ImageNotAvailable.jpg');
    }

    function gotImageElement(item) {
        item.addEventListener('onerror', callImageError(item));
//        item.onerror(callImageError(item))
    }

    var mImg = document.getElementsByClassName("NotFoundMain");
    for (var i = 0; i < mImg.length; i++) {
            gotImageElement(mImg[i])
        }
        //mImg.forEach(gotImageElement)
    });
```

But this is not working even if image is there this event is fired and i get no image found image
Am i doing something wrong.
Please help

Comment: Not related to your problem, but an Image Control uses `ImageUrl`, not `src`

Comment: Sorry for that it was a typo but the main thing why my error event is not working,it is always firing for each element

Answer (score 4):

The event name is `error`, not `onerror`. Another issue is that you have to provide a function to be called when an event occurs instead calling it immediately.

```
item.addEventListener('error', function(){ callImageError(item) });
```

Comment: I tried both ,both are not working

Comment: @ParshuramKalvikatte It may be also an issue with `$(document).ready`. When document is ready then `error` events have already been fired probably. You need to register your listeners before it happens.